# dc.numberDisplay showing count for single group, not count of number of groups

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have data that looks like this:

```
var records = [
        {id: '1', cat: 'A'},
        {id: '2', cat: 'A'},
        {id: '3', cat: 'B'},
        {id: '4', cat: 'B'},
        {id: '5', cat: 'B'},
        {id: '6', cat: 'C'}
 ];
```

I want to create a dc.numberDisplay that displays the **count** of the number of unique categories, 3 in the example data above (A, B, & C).

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data); // init crossfilter
// create dimension based on category
var categoryDimension = ndx.dimension(
  function (d) {
    return d.category;
  }
);
// Group by category
var categoryGroup = categoryDimension.group();

var categoryCount = dc.numberDisplay('#category-count'); // An empty span
categoryCount
  .group(categoryGroup)
  .valueAccessor(
    function (d) { return d.value; }
  );
```

The problem is that the numberDisplay displays **2** instead of 3. When debugging, I found that when the valueAccessor is called, `d` is the count of the number of elements of category A instead of the count of the number of categories.

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Nathan's solution, here is a working code snippet (ES2016 style)

```
const categoryDimension = claims.dimension(
        (d) => {
          return d.cat;
        }
      );

const categoryGroup = categoryDimension.groupAll().reduce(
  (p, v) => { // add element
    const cat = v.cat;
    const count = p.categories.get(cat) ||  0;
    p.categories.set(cat, count + 1);
    return p;
  },

  (p, v) => { // remove element
    const cat = v.cat;
    const count = p.categories.get(cat);
    if (count === 1) {
      p.categories.delete(cat);
    } else {
      p.categories.set(cat, count - 1);
    }
    return p;
  },

  () => { // init
    return {
      categories: new Map()
    };
  });

categoryCount
  .group(categoryGroup)
  .valueAccessor(
    (d) => {
      return d.categories.size;
    }
  );
```

Comment: The best way to debug this is to start with crossfilter. Do a console.debug("groups", categoryGroup.top(Infinity)); to see what crossfilter is handing off to DC.js. I suspect you need more to your group than just .group()

Comment: The categoryGroup contains the following:

"[{"key":"B","value":3},{"key":"A","value":2},{"key":"C","value":1}]"

Looks like it is creating a 'group' for each category and counting it

Comment: Looks like the numberDisplay just looks at the first group, var valObj = group.value ? group.value() : group.top(1)[0]; (https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/number-display.js line 81). You will need to use GroupAll to put your entire dataset into a single group and then use reduce to keep track of the number of unique categories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use groupAll() since the number-display only looks at the top group. Then provide custom reduce functions to track unique categories. Finally, when DC.js pulls the value from the top group (there is only one) - just return the number of categories (which is the number of keys in the p object).

```
var categoryGroup = categoryDimension.groupAll().reduce(
  function (p, v) { //add
    if(p[v.cat]) {
      p[v.cat]++;
    } else {
      p[v.cat] = 1;
    }
    return p;
  },
  function (p, v) { //remove
    p[v.cat]--;
    if(p[v.cat] === 0) {
      delete p[v.cat];
    }
    return p;
  },
  function () { //init
    //initial p - only one since using groupAll
    return {};
  }
);

console.debug("groups", categoryGroup.value());

dc.numberDisplay('#category-count')
  .group(categoryGroup)
  .valueAccessor(
    function (d) { return Object.keys(d).length; }
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed. I have updated the original question with a solution snippet